# What is the reason for the strips on the nose of the Embraer E175

Tags: feature-identification, nose, embraer-e-jet

Recently I boarded a KLM flight with an Embraer E175, when I noticed the strips on the nose

(see image, marked with the black circle).
[image]
*Own image*

This Embraer E190 also has it:
[image]
[Image source](https://www.airplane-pictures.net/photo/398291/ph-exd-klm-cityhopper-embraer-erj-190-190-100/)

Whereas this A320 does not have it, is it an Embraer specific feature? What is it for?
 [image]

[Image source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm2eqPh3ctM)

Comment: You need a closer look, the [A320 also have those](https://live.staticflickr.com/7149/6756942887_a2919f9963_b.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of another answer, but they are lightning arresters which conduct electrical charges away from the radome and avionics contained therein to the metal airframe where it can pass through and exit the aircraft without harm.

Comment: They're used more to discharge static buildup on the radome than handle lightning strikes.

Comment: Well and what is lightning but a large static electric discharge?

Comment: Fair enough. But the point is to not have a large static discharge at all